# Should I reuse my modem/router access point name/password on an additional access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a smart wired home but there's no WiFi to upstairs. I've configured a TP-Link router as an *access point* and connected it to an ethernet wall socket which connects to my modem/router downstairs.

It's not a mesh enabled system and I'm wondering if there are any problems in using the same WiFi name and password, or if it is better to use a different Access Point name, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same Wireless name and password. You may find you need to disconnect and then reconnect a device when you move from one floor to the other if you're still connected to the more distant (weaker signal) access point.  This force your device to reconnect to the closer (stronger) connection.  Simply toggle-off, then toggle-on your device's WiFi.

You can use different Wireless name and password and then you'll know you need to re-connect, because you will know for sure which access point you currently on.

Try the first method and if it works as you need it to work, great.

Otherwise use the second method.